# How to count times I have clicked a shape?

Tags: excel, vba, click-counting

I created a simple aim practice game, where you click on a circle that teleports when you click on it.

I want to count how many times you have clicked the circle.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 3):

Add your shapes to a worksheet, then right-click and "Assign Macro". As an example, it can look like this:

[image]

Then your code in a VBA module catches the click events from the shapes (because you linked the shape to the macro in the previous step):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Oval1_Click()
    Dim countCell As Range
    Set countCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D7")
    countCell = countCell + 1
End Sub

Sub Oval2_Click()
    Dim countCell As Range
    Set countCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D7")
    countCell = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Right click on the shape and choose Format Shape. There are also helper button on the Home ribbon. You can get lots of information on a google search for this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to insert commandbutton from developer option and use that as shape.
here is code that will count number of times it is clicked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Static cnt As Long
cnt = cnt + 1
Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "I have been clicked " & cnt & " times"
End Sub
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct, it is not the correct answer. I up-voted for your first attempt.